# Macbook pro 13" (2018) compatible external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

Can someone recommend a 27" or 24" monitor that works with MacBook Pro 13" (2018 with 4 thunderbolt ports) connected through HDMI or DisplayPort (not VGA). The budget is 250$ at most, purpose is mostly reading and coding and writing). I can only find USB-C like monitors which are too expensive.

I had eye on Dell P2719H but there have been several reports that it does not detect signal from mac over HDMI which seems to be prevalent for Dell brand (apparently, Dell has issues with compliance to HDMI standards).

Comment: Any HDMI capable monitor should be able to work if you use a suitable HDMI-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the DELL U2414H since 2014 on different MBP and MBA, which is a 24" predecessor of the one you mentioned. I haven't had any connection or display issues, and would recommend Dell displays especially for their great value.

It works best with [this USB-C to DP cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07S7NTNHC/?tag=luut-21), because the screen is set to auto sleep when the macbook is locked. Connecting it via HDMI also works, but when you lock the MacBook you have to turn off the Monitor or wait till the monitor puts itself to sleep. I used to use the Apple Multiport Adapter.

I think you won't have connection problems when you use a high quality HDMI adapter or connect it via a USB-C to DP cable.

Comment: Do you happen to have a MBP 2018 and later with all T3 connectors? There is an interesting description: of one of the issues with connecting MBP to an external monitor, but at least it connects in that case. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/08/24/macbook-pro-external-monitor-display-problem/

Comment: Yes, I'm using a MBP 16" (2019) and MBA (2020) with this monitor and don't experience the sub pixel rendering issue although using the YCrCb format.